# Ошибка в Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Ошибка в Fragment не пойму как исправить, объясните пожалуйста почему в Fragment код работает не так как в Activity

```
public class Fragment_Menu_list_Tasks_Prapor_1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_list_task_prapor_1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ImageButton back = requireView().findViewById(R.id.back);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Navigation.findNavController(view)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_fragment_Menu_list_Tasks_Prapor_1_to_fragment_Menu_list_Tasks_Prapor);
            }
        });

        final ImageButton quick_menu = requireView().findViewById(R.id.quick_menu);

        quick_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(Fragment_Menu_list_Tasks_Prapor_1.this, quick_menu);
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quick_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());

                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Ошибка

```
error: incompatible types: Fragment_Menu_list_Tasks_Prapor_1 cannot be converted to Context
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(Fragment_Menu_list_Tasks_Prapor_1.this, quick_menu);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в активити что-то требует `Context`, то `this` передают, потому что активити наследуется от `Context`. Фрагмент же не наследуется от Context, но его можно получить с помощью метода `getContext()`

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getContext(), quick_menu);
```

Либо контекст можно получить из `View`, которая приходит в `OnClick`

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), quick_menu);
```

Comment: То есть мне нужно заменить `this` на `getContext()`? И получится что то тип такого PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getContext().Fragment_Menu_list_Tasks_Prapor_1, quick_menu);?

Comment: @Karpuha `Fragment_Menu_list_Tasks_Prapor_1.this.getContext()`, но можно и просто `getContext()`, так как у `View.OnClickListener` нет метода getContext, который бы перекрывал аналогичный фрагмента